# What does this vehicle transport?

Tags: ground-operations

I've seen on many airports a lot of vehicles transporting some "brown boxes".

[image: ags]

Any idea of what is this?
 (I don't ask what's exactly inside this box, just in general) 
Source: [123rf.com](http://www.123rf.com/photo_5673542_air-transportation-airplane-loading-cargo.html)

[image: klma330]

[image: a330]

What that may be?  Baggage? : in case that boxes contain baggage, why don't they put it as loose baggage or in ULD's. May that be other type of cargo?

Comment: Where was this picture taken and when?

Comment: Sao Paulo Guarulhos 9/21/15

Comment: Do you remember in which company they were loading in?

Comment: It was a SWISS A340

Comment: Brazil also exports organic cocoa to Switzerland, that might be what you are asking for.

Comment: Lots of cargo is packed in cardboard before being packed on a pallet.

Comment: Why is it that?

Comment: @kepler22b: Are you serious? What do you pack things in to move them from your attic to your cellar? Discarded refrigerators?

Comment: Well, some people said that those boxes may cointain baggage

Comment: Also, editing in the source of your images is generally considered good form, though the Getty Image contains obvious copyright info. It might be wise to see if you can find a non-copyright image to use in its place (unless, of course, you have permission to use the image).

Comment: Those are just cargo AND passenger luggages. Yes ! Cardboard boxes aren't that strong (you don't want to put a 50-60lbs luggage on top of), but they have a nice tendency to fit very well when stacked one on top the other. So, good practice is to group and tie/secure them on palettes for ease of loading and space management. Being passenger boxed goods, mail, non passenger cargo, special cargo like dozens of microwaves (...) if it's a cardboard box, put them together with other cardboard boxes. As simple as that. There is nothing mistical or disturbing about, standard/legal/efficient practice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is rather broad and somewhat unclear, but what you have is a picture of a baggage tug and cart.

The carts are loaded with passenger baggage or cargo, then strings of them are pulled to the aircraft by the tug before being loaded on to the plane.

Based on the additional pictures, I think what you're after would be called `palletized cargo`. It's stuff, put in boxes, placed on pallets, wrapped with [stretch wrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stretch_wrap), with a net thrown over the top and hooked down to keep it from sliding off the pallet.

It is most likely *not* passenger baggage. That's either loaded one piece at a time by hand, or in a [ULD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_load_device).

If you're asking what's in *those* particular boxes, you'd have to zoom in quite close to find a label on a box to even have a chance of figuring it out. Just about anything can be and is shipped in a brown cardboard box, from anywhere to anywhere in the world. *This* question is *far* too broad and off topic for Aviation.SE, and probably *any* SE.

Comment: humorless downvoter seems to have struck here, too. :(  Considering the question was nearly closed when I originally answered, I don't think it was that bad...

Comment: It's too small a change for me to suggest an edit, but you want `palletize` (to place on pallets) in place of `palatalized` (a phonetic term).

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom thank you sir. That's what I get for relying on the red, squiggly underline, instead of thinking...

Answer (score 1):

Those are cargo and baggages. Yes passenger flights do transport cargo other than baggages.

Answer (score -3):

[shipping batteries](https://www.ups.com/media/news/en/shipping_batteries.pdf) could be a possibility.

Comment: Not on a passenger flight, it couldn't. But it could be millions of other things.

Comment: humorless downvoter has no humor